# Adding ID to a new created object as3

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

i got a question , i create a new child, a circle but i dont know how can i give it an ID, so i can access it whenever i want, even if i move it , the problem is my function new_sond creates more than 1 object, so i want to give them the ID in the function for example for the 1 object "1" for the 2nd "2" and so on, i dont have any idea how to do it, i tried to search but didnt find anything, the trace(name) won`t be usefull becouse i create more objects with the same name...

here is the code for creating the object :

```
function new_sond(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    if (i<9)
    {
    i++;
    id[i]=i;
    var btn:Sprite = new Sprite();  
    btn.graphics.beginFill(0x0066FF, 1);
    btn.graphics.drawCircle(400, 300, 25);
    btn.graphics.endFill();
    var textField = new TextField();
    textField.mouseEnabled=false;
    textField.text = i;
    textField.width = 10; 
    textField.height = 17;
    textField.x = 395; // center it horizontally
    textField.y = 292; // center it vertically
    cx[i]=textField.x;
    cy[i]=textField.y;
    btn.addChild(textField);
    this.addChild(btn);
    }
}
```

And this is the code for moving the object :

```
this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownH);
this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUpH);
function mouseDownH(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    var object = evt.target;
    object.startDrag();
}

function mouseUpH(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    var obj = evt.target;
        obj.stopDrag();
}
```

The question is how do i give an ID to each created object so i can check it even if i move the object.
Thank you very much !!!!

Comment: Why are you creating objects with the same name? Your code only appears to create up to 9 objects, and you increment `i` every time. It's not even setting the `name` property. What exactly is the purpose of `id[i]=i;`? To me, it still sounds like you should subclass the Sprite class and create your own properties to track. Are you looking to create your own unique id to use, and why doesn't `name` satisfy that requirement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `name` property on the [Sprite class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Sprite.html#propertySummary). This property is inherited from the [DIsplayObject class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#name). Here is a summary of the property from the documentation.

The property is a String and you set or retrieve it from its setter/getter implementations in DisplayObject:

```
public function get name():String
public function set name(value:String):void
```

This property is part of ActionScript 3.0 and is available in runtime versions starting with AIR 1.0, Flash Player 9, Flash Lite 4 (which means it is available in later version as well).

It can throw an `IllegalOperationError` though. This is thrown if you attempt to set the property on an object placed on the timeline via the Flash authoring tool.

Here is the example given in the [`DisplayObject#name`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#name) property documentation. The example creates two Sprite objects and traces their names when they are clicked.

```
 import flash.display.Sprite;
 import flash.events.MouseEvent;

 var circle1:Sprite = new Sprite();
 circle1.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
 circle1.graphics.drawCircle(40, 40, 40);
 circle1.name = "circle1";
 addChild(circle1);
 circle1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, traceName);

 var circle2:Sprite = new Sprite();
 circle2.graphics.beginFill(0x0000FF); 
 circle2.graphics.drawCircle(140, 40, 40);
 circle2.name = "circle2";
 addChild(circle2);
 circle2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, traceName);

 function traceName(event:MouseEvent):void {
     trace(event.target.name);
 }
```

If this does not work for you, you can always create your own class that is a sub-class of Sprite and add your own properties to track an "id" field for whatever purposes you seek.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could put your objects in an array and rely on their array position as an Id.

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled on this question and thought it relevant to point out that AS3 also has a built-in utility for generating unique names for Objects

[NameUtil.createUniqueName](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/utils/NameUtil.html#createUniqueName%28%29)